# Does NSLog executes in ipod / iphone?

Tags: iphone, nslog

Does NSLog executes in iPod/iPhone ? i have googled it .. could'nt find anything..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does work exactly like on the desktop.

You can see the results in your Xcode run log or, if gdb is not attached, in the console log of your iPhone. The Xcode organizer has a tab which shows the devices console log.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know NSLog does execute on the iPhone. You can get access to the output from the Organizer window in XCode with your device attached (Check the Console tab).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, NSLog works for iphone/ipod/ipad.