# No debug output after waiting for App Launch via Push Notification

Tags: debugging, notifications, push, nslog

I found an answer to my original problem here:

[Debugging App When Launched by Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239000/debugging-app-when-launched-by-push-notification)

I want to be able to debug when the app is launched via  push notification. This works great and the app sits and waits till its launched remotely. However.. NSLog does not appear to be outputting to the debugger and I cannot see why. I can stick in break points and step through the app (view the values) but when NSLog is called nothing is displayed in the debugger itself.

Has anyone managed to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was having trouble trying to find the logs as well.  See owenfi's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25225961/1073754