# iOS - How to view NSLog and printf output in ssh session on phone?

Tags: ios, xcode, printf, nslog, syslog

I have a simple iPhone App that uses an `NSLog` and several `printf` statements.  The app is a simple test app that I created to test serial communication on the iPhone (3GS).  Obviously I can not test serial com with the iOS Simulator, so I have my device unplugged from the computer after I click `Run` from within Xcode.  I installed syslogd from Cydia, and `tail /var/log/syslog` allows me to monitor certain log messages.

However when I open my app and it reaches the `NSLog` portion of the code I don't see the message appear in `/var/log/syslog` I also don't see the `printf` statements output in the `syslog` file for the app.

Is there a file that exists on the iPhone itself that contains the output from these statements, or do I need to specify my app to output to `/var/log/syslog`?

I am content with opening another file if it exists on the phone that contains the contents of the log messages.  Basically I want to be able to see the contents of the log messages while I am `sshed` into the phone so I can see what is going on.  And obviously using the Console output in Xcode is not an option because the phone isn't connected to the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `tail /var/log/syslog`? It only shows the last 15 lines of the log. Maybe try using `tail -f /var/log/syslog`. I just tested that and it logged my my simple `NSLog(@"LOL");` just fine. I was able to see it via ssh and everything.

Comment: can not found /var/log/syslog in ios9.0.2

Answer (score 1):

You write to [syslog](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/syslog.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/syslog) you should be calling the syslog function.

NSLog output can be seen as shown in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318342/what-happens-to-nslog-info-when-running-on-a-device).

printf will only go to stdout.

I would try not to use NSLog and stdout for logging in the same app - use NSLog for all logging there. Or with more work ue a logging framework like [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack/wiki/CustomLoggers) that allows more flexibility including other loggers which could include syslog, thus having one logging function that you can redirect to different outputs at runtime.

Comment: How can I view stdout for my printf statements?  I moved my NSLog statement and was able to see it in syslog, but was not able to see the printf statements.

Comment: I don't know which is one reason to use NSLog or another logger to allow you to redirect.